# How to make text bigger in label?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I am wanting to use NSMutableAttributedString to change part of the original string and make part of the text bigger then the original. However, it is not working because of something very minor that I can't figure out. Here is my code:

```
NSString *combineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ...];
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:combineString];
NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(5, 4); // 4 characters, starting at index 22

[string beginEditing];

[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                   value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50]
                   range:selectedRange];

[string endEditing];
mainCell.label.text = combineString;
```

Comment: That will not work, a label's text fontsize is the same for the whole string. Split it to 2 or 3 labels, where one part has a bigger font.

Comment: @ott-- Nope: NSAttributedString is available as of iOS 6.0.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon Thanks for clearing things up a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re setting the `text` property, which takes an NSString—your attributed string, `string`, isn’t actually going anywhere. Try this:

```
mainCell.label.attributedText = string;
```

Comment: Oh, and if you’re not using ARC, make sure you release `string` after handing it off to the label.

Comment: This makes beautiful sense. And I have thought about this and I changed it and was getting an error by using "mainCell.label.text = string. So I figured that must be wrong. But attributedText of course obviously works. Thanks a million for answering with my stupidity lol